# What causes the difference between these 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I create the following dataframe "names"

```
0       Max
1    Albert
2     Marie
3     Niels
Name: name, dtype: object
```

and save it to the disk using

```
names.to_csv("names.csv", index=False)
```

and load the same csv file using

```
names_new = pd.load_csv("names.csv")
```

the names_new looks like this

```
        name
0     Max
1  Albert
2   Marie
3   Niels
```

and

```
names.equals(names_new)
```

returns false.

When I check they both have the same length. So what is causing the difference and how can I make sure saving a dataframe to csv and loading it again will create the same dataframe?

Comment: maybe `names.equals(names_new['name'])`  Or `names.reset_index(drop=True).equals(names_new['name'])` ?

Comment: The first one is not a DataFrame but a Series, convert using `names_new['name']`

Comment: `load_csv`? My Pandas version has `read_csv`, but no `load_csv`. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For compare Series select column `name`:

```
print(names.equals(names_new['name']))
```

If possible not default index in `names` use:

```
print(names.reset_index(drop=True).equals(names_new['name']))
```